# Cant find Property Editor Settings when creating new element

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm currently following this tutorial: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html

I'm on the final part: Configure the field editor parameters > Create the field type item

I can't seem to find my get my item from the core database for the Property Editor value. All I get is the following:

[image]

Am I missing something?

I'm currently on Sitecore 9.0 - I cannot upgrade.

Comment: Based on the steps described you should be on master DB and look for "/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic". Why are you searching for it on the Core DB?

Comment: Following  on the tutorial, it said: _Property Editor – point to the item you created earlier. For example, select the property editor for the Video item._ From what I can tell its the item I created in the core database at _/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings_

Comment: You are correct. That field "Property Editor" looks for value in the CORE db. Are you not seeing this folder "/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings" in the CORE db?

Comment: The screenshot in my original post shows what I can see when I click on Property Editor. It looks like its only looking at the master database rather than the core database. If I manually add the guid key (enabling raw values) it just says I have a broken link

Comment: The field "Property Editor" of this template "{A60EDCAF-1285-46B5-8380-D790BB8C8708}" should be of type "Droptree" with source as "DataSource={0E723521-4594-4785-AECE-CEB7BB2FB4E0}&DatabaseName=core". Please check what you have at your end.

Comment: Yes! that worked. It seems like it went missing at some point. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Awesome, great that I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `Property Editor` of the template `/System/Forms/Field Type` - `{A60EDCAF-1285-46B5-8380-D790BB8C8708}` was missing the source.

Updated the source of the `Droptree` with source as `DataSource={0E723521-4594-4785-AECE-CEB7BB2FB4E0}&DatabaseName=core`.